# SELECT rows that are referenced less than x times in another table

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I have two tables, my reservable "weekend":

```
id bigint(20) unsigned,
label varchar(64),
date_start date,
max_attendees smallint(5) unsigned
```

And my attendees:

```
id bigint(20) unsigned,
name varchar(64),
email varchar(255),
weekend bigint(20) unsigned
```

I want to select all weekends that have attendees less than their max_attendees. This includes weekends that have **0** attendees.

*Note: I also need to ignore weekend with id "1"*;

Currently, this works fine with PHP (I'm using Wordpress for mysql access), like so:

```
$weekends = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $weekends_table
                                   WHERE id <> 1", ARRAY_A);

$open_weekends = array();

foreach ($weekends as $weekend) {
    $id = $weekend['id'];
    $attendees = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(id) as attendees
                                    FROM $attendees_table
                                    WHERE weekend = $id", ARRAY_A);

    if ( $attendees['attendees'] < $weekend['max_attendees'] ) {
        $weekend['attendees'] = $attendees['attendees'];
        $open_weekends[] = $weekend;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to do this in MySQL without the PHP? My knowledge of MySQL doesn't extend that far. Can you suggest a query?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the reason my PHP works is because the second query `get_row` returns zero in cases where there were no attendees, which meant that I was still able to compare it with max_attendees. This was addressed in my chosen answer by adding `OR COUNT(a.name) IS NULL)` to include weekends with no attendees, and not just weekends with at least one attendee, but less than the maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause

This is untested, so you may have to play with it, but here's the gist:

```
SELECT w.*, COUNT(a.name)
FROM weekend w
LEFT JOIN attendees a
  ON w.id = a.weekend
WHERE w.id <> 1
GROUP BY w.id
HAVING (COUNT(a.name) < w.max_attendees) OR (COUNT(a.name) IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. But it gives me only the weekends that have at least _one_ attendee. So, I have two weekends with _zero_ attendees and these do not show up in the list. That's the main reason I had to do it in PHP. It seems like the `COUNT` is acting as a filter on events with zero attendees, since it can only do a `JOIN` if it finds at least one attendee.

Comment: @LeoDeBruyn ah, that's because `<` doesn't compare `null` values. I edited my answer to use a `LEFT JOIN` with an `OR` condition in the `HAVING` clause. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you! Not only does this work perfectly, but I feel like I have leveled up in my MySQL knowledge. I now know: the `HAVING` clause, use of `OR` within it, and counting `NULL` to count columns that are not referenced by anything. I was able to take this query and write several more that I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be this:

```
SELECT COUNT($attendees_table.id) as attendees
       attendees_table.max_attendees as maximum
FROM weekends_table, attendees_table
WHERE attendees_table.weekend = weekends_table.id
GROUP BY weekends_table.id
```

You could use a `JOIN ON attendees_table`.

This should be possible as well:

```
SELECT COUNT(attendees_table.id) as attendees
       weekends_table.max_attendees as maximum
FROM weekends_table, attendees_table
WHERE attendees_table.weekend = weekends_table.id
GROUP BY weekends_table.id
HAVING attendees < maximum
```

This is all untested. I don't have your tables or data, but it might get you going?

Ah, it didn't get what you wanted. To include zero attendees you can use a subselect:

```
SELECT  weekends_table.id AS weekend_id
FROM weekends_table
WHERE weekends_table.max_attendees > (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                      FROM attendees_table 
                                      WHERE attendees_table.weekend = weekends_table.id)
```

It should return weekend id's where there's at least room for one more attendee. Again, completely untested, but perhaps it works?

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned up a couple things (added comma, changed attendees_table.max_attendees to weekends_table.max_attendees) and both of these got me the same result as Jeff's answer. That is, it returns weekends that have at least _one_ attendee and are less than the maximum, but it does _not_ include weekends with _zero_ attendees. The goal is to get a list of _all_ weekends that have openings left, including those with nobody yet signed up.

Comment: I ended up using Jeff's answer, but I appreciate you taking the time. The thing that I was getting stuck on was needing to `COUNT` instances of `NULL` to get the open weekends that had no attendees yet.